# Django not serving static files with even after collectstatic

Tags: python, linux, django, ubuntu, vps

i'm having problems with django static files in production.I know django requires that you collectstatic during deployment, which i did. The real problem comes when i try to access my page on the browser and i get a 403 forbidden error on all static files. I tried changing my permissions and ownership of var/www/html folders to 755 and files to 644 but still no luck. How do i make my static files load?

[image: 403 error]

settings.py

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'hidden'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com','www.example.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'powerlineproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'powerlineproject.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

[here is my directory screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Cnj.jpg)

nginx.conf

```
user www-data www-data;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
    include /etc/nginx.custom.events.d/*.conf;
}

http {
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;

    keepalive_timeout 20;
    client_header_timeout 20;
    client_body_timeout 20;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    send_timeout 20;

    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_comp_level 4;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    include mime.conf;
    charset UTF-8;

    open_file_cache max=100000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;

    server_tokens off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    include proxy.conf;
    include fcgi.conf;
```

Comment: [`collectstatic` isn't the only thing you need to do](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/). Are you using something like [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)?

Comment: post your settings.py and screenshot of your project directory structure.

Comment: edited my question and included my setting.py and included the image for the directory folder..i'm using nginx on an ubuntu 14.04 vps.

Comment: There's something wonky going on... your browser request /static/<stuff>/base.css and got a 301 (redirect) to /static/stuff/base.css/ as in your server treated it as a directory ... please post your nginx conf

Comment: I edited my post. I noticed this problem too but since im a noob i just dont know where im going wrong and why im getting 301 and 403 errors.